# Increment class/ID to carry function to cloned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, populate

I have a section of code that contains a dropdown and 3 readonly input fields. The input fields are populated using javascript, this works fine on it's own using the below code -

```
$(document).on('change', '.unit', function(e) {

//Getting Value
var role = $('.unit option:selected').data('role');
    var power = $('.unit option:selected').data('power');
    var type = $('.unit option:selected').data('type');


//Setting Value
$(".role").val(role);
    $(".power").val(power);
    $(".type").val(type);
});
```

I am wanting to clone the element using this code -

```
 //define template
var template = $('.duplicate-sections .form-section:first').clone();

//define counter
var sectionsCount = 1;

//add new section
$('body').on('click', '.addsection', function() {

    //increment
    sectionsCount++;

    //loop through each input
    var section = template.clone(true, true).find(':input').each(function(){

        //set id to store the updated section number
        var newId = this.id + sectionsCount;

        //update for label
        $(this).prev().attr('for', newId);

        //update id
        this.id = newId;

    }).end()

    //inject new section
    .appendTo('.duplicate-sections');
    return false;
});

//remove section
$('.duplicate-sections').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    //fade out section
    $(this).closest('.form-section').fadeOut(300,             function(){
    $(this).closest('.form-section').empty();
    });
    return false;
});
```

The cloning process works and the dropdown and the inputs are cloned. However when populating the cloned input fields it uses the values from the parent not the clone.

My html is -

```
<div class="duplicate-sections">
            <div class="form-section">
        <div class="form-group row">
<label for="inputFirstName" class="col-form-label col-sm-3 text-left text-sm-right">Unit Type</label>
<div class="col-sm-3">
   <select name="unit" id="unit" class="form-control unit"><option value="">Select</option><option 
data-role="HQ" data-power="4" data-type="Company Commander" value="1">Ehrwig Arellano</option>
<option data-role="HQ" data-power="6" data-type="Company Commander" value="2">Ehrwig 
Arellano</option>
<option data-role="HQ" data-power="2" data-type="Tempestor Prime" value="3">Tempestor Prime</option>
</select></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 increment_controls">
    <input type="text" id="role" name="role" class="form-control role" readonly placeholder="Role">
</div>
            <div class="col-sm-1 increment_controls">
    <input type="text" id="power" name="power" class="form-control power" readonly placeholder="PL">
</div> 
            <div class="col-sm-3 increment_controls">
    <input type="text" id="type" name="type" class="form-control type" readonly placeholder="Type">
</div>
            
</div>
        
                <label for="inputFirstName" class="col-form-label col-sm-3 text-left text-sm-right"> 
</label><input class="remove col-sm-9" type="button" value="Remove Unit"></input>
      </div>
        </div>
        <label for="inputFirstName" class="col-form-label col-sm-3 text-left text-sm-right"></label> 
<input class="addsection col-sm-9" type="button" value="Add Unit"></input>
```

The whole thing can be found here - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Foster83/tgxd5cmr/57/)

Comment: This what you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/ob2u8vme/

Comment: That is exactly what I want, I knew I needed to use .closest and .find but could not for the life of me work out where to put them. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update change event handler script for Unit as here you need to update input fields from the relevant form section only and not for all input fields.

see below code

```
$(document).on('change', '.unit', function(e) {
   
    //Getting Value
    var $option = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var role = $option.data('role');
        var power = $option.data('power');
        var type = $option.data('type');
    
    
    //Setting Value
    var $parent = $(this).closest('.form-section');
    $parent.find(".role").val(role);
        $parent.find(".power").val(power);
        $parent.find(".type").val(type);
    });
```

[Demo JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3rd5ykwx/)